# How to make all button same size in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am making a simple calculator and want all my buttons to re-size to the size of one button that I have  set. This was possible with VS2010 but I don't know how to do this in Qt Creator. I have tried using layout but no luck. Is this possible?

- I have 16 buttons in grid layout.
- I resize one button changing both its height and width.
- Now I want all buttons to conform to the same size.

The problem I am facing is that when I use layouts, it resets the height of the button to default so I can't really create custom size of buttons?

[image]

Comment: Define min size (particularly min height)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
setMinimumSize( int minw, int minh )
setMaximumSize( int maxw, int maxh )
```

with minw=maxw   and minh =maxh

```
setMinimumSize( 40, 40 )
setMaximumSize( 40, 40 )
```

forcing to be 40x40 of size

Comment: But than I have to set this individually for all buttons? Is there a way to all other buttons can take this from one?

Comment: On the property stylesheet paste it:
QPushButton
{
min-width: 40px;
min-height: 40px;
max-width: 40px;
max-height: 40px;
}

Comment: @zadane In Qt Creator (UI designer window), you can "COPY"(Ctrl + C) and "PASTE"(Ctrl + V) the existing button with the properties, if your don't want to set them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

For setting fixed size:

```
void QWidget::setFixedSize ( int w, int h )
void QWidget::setFixedSize ( const QSize & s )
```

You can take the size of another button:

```
Btn1.setFixedSize(40, 40);
Btn2.setFixedSize(Btn1.size());
Btn3.setFixedSize(Btn1.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use horizontal and vertical spacers , take a look at this :
[Qt Spacers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E2KOphwZMg)
starting from minute 7:02

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it.

```
QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().setStyleSheet(
        'QPushButton { min-width: 140px; min-height: 40px; max-width: 140px; max-height: 40px; }')
```

Must be run in a **main application thread** (i.e. "gui thread"). Won't work if run in a worker thread.